# Reg:Adding two measures from MDX into one field

Tags: sql, reporting-services, mdx

I have two measures in cube. I want to add two values from each measure and showing into one measure. basically adding two measure values into one.
How can I do.
thanks

Comment: Do you have any code? Please put a bit more effort into explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just define a calculated measure that is the sum of the other two measures.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new measure which sums two other measures:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MyNewMeasure] AS [Measures].[MyFirstMeasure] + [Measures].[MySecondMeasure]
SELECT {[Measures].[MyNewMeasure]} ON COLUMNS,
{ whatever } ON ROWS
FROM [CubeName]
```